# Не срабатывает return в фукнции на TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я недавно начал изучать TypeScript и столкнулся с проблемой.

```
function areEqual(objectA:object,objectB:object):boolean{
Object.keys(objectA).forEach(element => {
    if (objectA[element]!=objectB[element]){
        console.log(1) // 1
        return false;
    }
});
return true;
}

console.log(areEqual(obj1,obj2)) // true
```

Вызов функции выводит true, хотя условие для false срабатывает. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: ваш `return false;` работает в колбеке функции `forEach`, он не делает выход из функции `areEqual`

Comment: а ещё ваша проверка эквивалентности проигнорирует такое отличие `areEqual({a: 1}, {a: 1, b: 1})`

Comment: Для такой проверки, лучше использовать метод `some` или  `every`

Answer (score 1):

В функции `areEqual` всего один `return`

```
return true;
```

это становится заметно, если вынести определение callback для функции `forEach` отдельно

```
function areEqual(objectA:object,objectB:object):boolean{
    Object.keys(objectA).forEach(callback);
    return true;
}
```

Таким образом `areEqual` всегда возвращает `true`.

Чтобы работал `return false` вместо метода `.forEach` стоило использовать обычный цикл [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) или [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) либо [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Пример:

```
function areEqual(objectA:object,objectB:object):boolean{
    for(var keyA in objectA){
        if (objectA[keyA]!=objectB[keyB]){            
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```